# Windows 8.1 not booting

Tags: windows, restore

It all started when I was playing battlefront and was getting fairly low fps, so I started overclocking my graphics card  and processor to see if that would help, but when I was overclocking my processor using Intel extreme tuning utility it asked me to reboot, so I did.

But it never came back around.

When it came back of it said Recover, Windows needs to be fixed.

After inserting the install disk as requested I hit the enter key as prompted (to try again) but the error code changed, it now read:

The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.

File: \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
Error code: 0xc000000f.

I then booted from the instilation media (the disk) and selected refresh or something but the disk was locked (don't know how it knew as I never specified what disk to look in.

Next I tried resetting it to an earlier back up point, as I regularly update those for this event. But it errored saying:
"to use system restore, you must specify which windows instillation to restore.

Restart the computer, select an operating system, and then select system restore."

What kind of an error message is that?! When it says restart the computer which drive does it want me to boot and where do I select an operating system?

Next I Google it and typed all sorts of things to try and get it to work into CMD, none of which worked.

I also tried the fix boot option, to no avail.

Any suggestions are welcome.

EDIT: The PC in question is born and bread to overclock, it's has an i7 4790K and a gtx 770 direct cuii. I also cleared the cmos so the overlock is no longer applied at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it! It was really obvious as well!

When I cleared the cmos button on my motherboard it set the default boot device to my 120Gb SSD, which used to hold my windows on it. (before I got my new fancy M.2 one) and was erroring because it was deleted.

So I changed the boot order to load windows from the correct drive and; hey presto!

Thanks for absolutely nothing Microsoft technical support.

Answer (score 0):

If laptop or desktop, **see if you can change the settings in your BIOS**, you can google the manufacturer/model of your device to get the correct key to enter the BIOS settings GUI (Usually one of the F-keys or Delete)

If you cannot change the settings in the BIOS, I'm not sure what the next step would be for the laptop, **maybe try "Factory Defaults" in the BIOS**?

If it's a desktop, **see if your GPU (Graphics Card) has a reset switch**. I was able to do this when I experienced something similar during my crypto-currency mining days, and overclocking to try and increase my hash-rate.

There is also a possibility that you damaged some of your hardware while overclocking.

Comment: I've fixed it now! It turns out it was booting from the wrong device. How do I say that I've answered the question btw?